# MuMps/cache ( vista)

Tags: hl7, intersystems-cache, mumps

How List manager works. Can you write a few pages describing how it works - walk through the         processing starting with EN^VALM(List Template) and what TAG^ROUTINE it calls, where each input by the user and display by the system is created, where it can branch to and why.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly complex question.  Have you seen this documenation?  http://va.gov/vdl/documents/Infrastructure/List_Manager/list_manager_developer.pdf

Also there is a group of VistA users here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hardhats  They would be much more likely be to answer your questions.

Best wishes.